# Adding .0 to numbers without a decimal in access query

Tags: ms-access, numbers, decimal, ms-access-2010

I need to be able to add `.0` to integer numbers in access query. Please see example below

**Current Table**

```
61
61.5
68.0
70
72.5
84
```

**What I would like the table to look like**

```
61.0
61.5
68.0
70.0
72.5
84.0
```

The format of the field is text and would have to stay that way unfortunately due to a submission procedure we have to follow.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use Format function on text field if data is still of numeric type - no alpha characters.

Answer (score 1):

You talk of a `query` but you do not mention much detail about it.
As long as the `column` you are formating is a `numeric` data type only, then you can use:

`SELECT Format([columnName], "0.0") FROM tableName);`

Comment: Still works for me as long as text in that field is numeric regardless. I even recreated the table and query result seems fine.

Comment: Ah, good. Perhaps change the text in your answer to "as long as the column only contains numeric values" or so.